# ListFragment keeps being empty

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I want to populate a ListFragment with some Data obtained from an API Endpoint. I first tested it with a ListView - which worked but now changed it into a ListFragment.

Now the List isn't populated anymore. I tested if the hashmap might be empty but it is not the case.

Now I am a bit clueless - maybe you can see the mistake I made:

```
public class AuftrageFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auftrag_view, container, false);
        Context context = getContext();
        final SharedPreferences tokenStore = context.getSharedPreferences("TokenStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = tokenStore.getString("token", null);
        if (token == null) {
            StartFragment start = new StartFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, start).commit();

        }
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String[] from = {"auftragsnummer", "schadensbild", "termin"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.auftragsnummer, R.id.schadensbild, R.id.termin};

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> auftragliste = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray ResponseArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i=0; i < ResponseArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject responseObject =  ResponseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String termin =  responseObject.getString("termin");
                        String schadensbild = responseObject.getString("schadensbild");
                        String auftragsnummer = responseObject.getString("auftragsnummer");
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("auftragsnummer", auftragsnummer);
                        map.put("schadensbild", schadensbild);
                        map.put("termin", termin);
                        auftragliste.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Context context = getContext();
        final SharedPreferences tokenStore = context.getSharedPreferences("TokenStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = tokenStore.getString("token", null);
        MainListRequest mainListRequest = new MainListRequest(token, responseListener, null);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
        queue.add(mainListRequest);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), auftragliste,R.layout.auftrag_view, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

auftrag_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Aufträge"
    android:id="@+id/uberschrift"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Items xml:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Auftragsnummer"
            android:id="@+id/auftragsnummer"
            android:elegantTextHeight="true"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Schadensbild"
            android:id="@+id/schadensbild"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Termin"
            android:id="@+id/termin" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i can not see a notifyDatasetChanged() anywhere. You should call it on the adapter once the backing data has changed/updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

```
(id for your listView).setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: The IDE tells me the view doesnt have this method

Comment: auftragliste.add(map); This code is written inside Listener block. It means your list is empty until Listener is called. So add these two lines and try after auftragliste.add(map); notifyDatasetChanged():setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Thanks this worked: so the ArrayList was empty untill the Lisitner was called, but since the Adapter didn't know about it he didn't update the view?

Comment: Yes exactly..enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call on the adapter#notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: When do I call it? It seems to have no effect - also it is called notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: After you have inserted the Data, and please do that call from the Main/UI Thread!

Answer (score 0):

what value you are expecting in AuftrageFragment.onCreateView for 'token' ?

onActivityCreated get called after onCreateView, can you check which fragment is in your container ? I am suspecting it is StartFragment

Comment: token is the oauth token. The fragment inside the container is StartFragment, but it can also be an other fragment

Comment: sorry i could not clear my point. if R.id.frame_container is your main container, you won't see AuftrageFragment as current visible fragment is StartFragment.

Check your view hierarchy